# How to duplicate a group of "tasks" that belong to the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates, copy, project

I'm in rails 3.0 and I'm working on a "project management" app. I'd like to duplicate an Item, which in my case is the "project", and at the same time, duplicate all tasks that belong to that item.

I stuffed my Item model with code I found here: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/repository/revisions/2704/diff/trunk/app/models/project.rb, which seems to do what I want, but I can't make it work for me.

I'd like any help you can offer--general or specific! thanks!

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :department
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :customer
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
has_many :tasks

def copy(item)
item = item.is_a?(Item) ? item : Item.find(item)
Item.transaction do
  # Tasks
  item.tasks.each do |task|
    new_task = Task.new
    new_task.copy_from(task)
    self.tasks << new_task
  end
  self.save
  Hook.call_hook(:model_item_copy_before_save, :source_item => item, :destination_item => self)
end
end


def self.copy_from(item)
begin
  item = item.is_a?(Item) ? item : Item.find(item)
  if item
    # clear unique attributes
    attributes = item.attributes.dup.except('id')
    copy = Item.new(attributes)
    copy.enabled_modules = item.enabled_modules
    copy.trackers = item.trackers
    copy.custom_values = item.custom_values.collect {|v| v.clone}
    return copy
  else
    return nil
  end
 rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  return nil
 end
end
```

Another thing--what is the Hook.call_hook...? I can't find any references to that on the web

Comment: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/repository/entry/trunk/lib/redmine/hook.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into [ActiveResource::Base#clone](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Base/clone).

It should probably work something like:

```
@project = @project2.clone
@project.tasks << @project2.tasks.map(&:clone)
@project.save
```

**EDIT:**

In the context of your model you could just have:

```
def self.copy(item)
  newitem = item.clone
  newitem.tasks << item.tasks.map(&:clone)
  return newitem
end
```

Then in your controller:

```
@project = Project.copy(@project_to_copy)
@project.save
```

Comment: does your code go into the controller? if so, what's absolutely necessary in my model? thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, you could just use it in the controller. I've edited my answer to include a model class method, as well.

Comment: xnm, quick question: how would I go about customizing fields while copying an item? How would I reset a particular field for all tasks? I appreciate your help!